# Two issues while loading html files into different div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a senior programmer but novice to javascript and CSS posibilities. Next is the description of what I have and what I want:

1. **Layout**  [image]
2. **My folders**:
   **Test_portal** : contains the iNat_main.html file and 2 subfolders:
   •   **iNat_files**: contains html files to be loaded into “submenu” div
   or “obs” div according to selection.
   •   **iNat_images**: contains images to be loaded within the html file that is loaded into the “obs” div according the selected “submenu” item.
3. **Issues**:
4. When I select a “menu” item it is loaded into the “submenu” div, but it doesn’t use the full area as shown in the layout. The scrollbars are too short.
5. When I select a “submenu” item it is loaded into an “obs” div, but
   it is displayed in submenu area of the layout (left side of the page) instead in the obs area of the layout (right side of the page).

**iNat_main.html**

```js
function load_menu(htmname){
document.getElementById("submenu").setAttribute("style","height:600px");
document.getElementById("submenu").innerHTML="<object type='text/html' data=" + htmname + "></object>";
}

function load_data(htmname){
document.getElementById("obs").setAttribute("style","height:600px");
document.getElementById("obs").innerHTML="<object type='text/html' data=" + htmname + "></object>";
}
```

```css
<style>
body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
header {
background-color: lightgreen;
padding: 2px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 8px;
color: black;
}
 
.inline-block-child {
float: left;
}
 
ul {
list-style-type: none;
text-align: right;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color:yellow;
}
li {
float: right;
border-right: 2px solid #000;
}
li a {
display: block;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 20px;
}
.bggrey {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.bgdata {
    background-color: cyan;
}
 
.float-container {
border: 3px solid #fff;
padding: 5px;
}
 
.float-child_l {
    background-color: lightgrey;
width: 35%;
float: left;
padding: 5px;
border: 2px solid black;
}
.float-child_r {
width: 65%;
float: left;
padding: 5px;
border: 2px solid green;
}
</style>
```

```html
<body>
<header role="banner">
<h1>My nature pictures</h1>
<h4> Origin=https://israel.inaturalist.org/observations?place_id=any&user_id=shmuelabinun&verifiable=any</h4>
</header>
<br>
 
<div id="menu">
<p dir="rtl"> Select what to show </p>
 
<ul>
<li><a href="#submenu" onclick=load_menu("./iNat_files/B_menu.html")>Birds</a></li>
<li><a href="#submenu" onclick=load_menu("./iNat_files/R_menu.html")>Reptiles</a></li>    
</ul>
</div>
<section class='container'>
<div class='float-container'>
    <div id ="submenu" class='float-child_l bggrey' width=40% scrollHeight="400px";>
      <p><dir="rtl" style="center">  ID=SubMenue </p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="obs" class='float-child_r bgdata' width=58% >
      <h2><text-align="right"> ID=obs for Data Selected </text-align></h2>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
 
</body>
</html>
```

**B_menu.html**

```js
function load_data(htmname){
document.getElementById("obs").setAttribute("style","height:600px");
document.getElementById("obs").innerHTML="<object type='text/html' data=" + htmname + "></object>";
}
```

```html
<body>
<object>
<p align=center><b> List of Birds</p>
<br>
<div>
<div id ="submenu" width=40%>
<section>
<p align=center><b> Select item to display </p>
<ol>
<li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#obs" onclick=load_data("./BID125.html")>אנפית בקר = Bubulcus ibis</a></li>
<li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#obs" onclick=load_data("./BID64.html")>אנפת לילה = Nycticorax nycticorax</a></li>
<li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#obs" onclick=load_data("./BID124.html")>ברכיה = Anas platyrhynchos</a></li>
<li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#obs" onclick=load_data("./BID72.html")>צוצלת = Streptopelia senegalensis</a></li>
<li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#obs" onclick=load_data("./BID126.html")>שלדג גמדי = Alcedo atthis</a></li>
</ol>
</section>
<br>
<div id="obs" class='child inline-block-child bgdata' width=58% >
<h2><text-align="right"> ID=obs for Data Selected </text-align></h2>
</div>
</div>
</object>
</body>
```

**BID125.html**

```css
<style>
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
[class*="col-"] {
border: 1px solid green;
}
.col-1 {width: 60%; padding: }
.col-2 {width: 40%; padding: }
.col-3 {width: 20.0%; padding: 0.5%;}
.zoomA {
width: 20.0%; padding: 0.5%;
height: auto;
transition: transform ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
.zoomA:hover {
transform: scale(5.0);
}
</style>
```

```html
<body>
<p align=center><b> Selected item data</p>
<div id ="obs" width=65%>
<p align=center><b>Birds</p>
<br>
<colgroup><col width:"50.0%;"/><col width:"50.0%;"/></colgroup>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1px" style="width:100%;">
<tr>
<th  align="left" class=col1>Bubulcus ibis</th>
<th  align="right" class=col2>ציפורים - אנפית בקר</th>
</tr>
</table>
<p align="right" dir="rtl"> #125 אגמון החולה 08/11/2018 בדרגת-מחקר </p><br>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="3px" style="width:70%;">
<colgroup><col width:"33.3%;"/><col width:"33.3%;"/><col width:"33.3%;"/></colgroup>
<tr>
<img src=../iNat_images/img125.jpg class="zoomA">
<img src=../iNat_images/img125_1.jpg class="zoomA">
</tr>
</table>
<br>
</div>
</body>
```

**Two IBIS images**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [**minimal**, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have edited my code to minimize it, but it seems that it lost some functionality (link does not work properly). I have just deleted some items from the menus.  My issues still exist.

Answer (score 0):

To load data like that you need to use [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX). `<object>` is not intended for loading HTML like that (in an edge case `<iframe>` could be used, but I would not recommend that either).

Here is a basic example of how external HTML can be loaded into a `<div>`. I use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for loading.
You can see that I'm using plain HTML in the HTML document and use JavaScript and eventlisteners to control what is going to happen.
The content of the document `page1.html` would just be the snippet of HTML need (so not body, head etc.).

```js
var menu, content;

const loadhtml = href => {
  fetch(href)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(html => {
      content.innerHTML = html;
    });
};

const onmenuclick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.nodeName == 'A') {
    let href = e.target.attributes['href'].value;
    loadhtml(href);
  }
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  menu = document.getElementById('menu');
  content = document.getElementById('content');

  menu.addEventListener('click', onmenuclick);
});
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
  <!--
    here I'm replacing the reference to an external HTML document
    with a data URL so that you can see how it works in this Stackoverflow snippet.
  -->
  <li><a href="data:text/html,<h1>Page 2</h1>">Page 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: I tried the fetch() function as proposed above and get the the error message:
"Fetch API cannot load file:///E:/my_portal/iNat_files/B_menux.html.
URL scheme "file" is not supported."

All my files are on local PC.

Comment: @Shmuel Fetch is used to fetch resources over a network. So, It won't work on local files. You can run it over `localhost`

Comment: What is the syntax to refer to a localhost file ?

Comment: @Shmuel In modern browsers there are restrictions on what you are allowed to do. One of them is the ability to load files asynchronously from the file system (like "file://blabla.html"). Therefore you need to run a webserver on your computer to make this code work. I wish I could point you to a specific setup in this regard, but there are so many solutions, opinions and constraints. Try read this first: [How do you set up a local testing server?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server) (Just read the first part).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all contributors. With a local help, all issues were solved.
I had to install Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS), edit the configuration file and launch it. Final working code is attached:

1. *index.html* -

```js
 
        function load_menu(htmname) {
            fetch(htmname /*, options */)
                .then((response) => response.text())
                .then((html) => {
                    document.getElementById("submenu").innerHTML = html;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.warn(error);
                });
        }

        function load_detailed_data(htmname) {
            fetch(htmname /*, options */)
                .then((response) => response.text())
                .then((html) => {
                    document.getElementById("obs").innerHTML = html;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.warn(error);
                });
        }
```

```css
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        .top_banner {
            background-color: lightgreen;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .top_banner h1 {
            font-size: xx-large;
        }

        .top_banner h4 {
            font-size: smaller;
        }

        .inline-block-child {
            float: left;
        }

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        [class*="col-"] {
            border: 1px solid green;
        }

        .zoomA {
            width: 20.0%;
            padding: 0.5%;
            height: auto;
            transition: transform ease-in-out 0.3s;
        }

        .zoomA:hover {
            transform: scale(3.0);
        }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            text-align: right;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        .main_menu li {
            float: right;
            border-right: 2px solid #000;
        }

        .main_menu li a {
            display: block;
            font-size: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .submenu {
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            direction:rtl;
        }

        .submenu p {
            padding-right:20px;
        }

        .submenu li {
            width:100%;
            direction:rtl;
        }

        .float-container {
            border: 3px solid #fff;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .main_pane {
            width:70%;
            height:100%;
            float: left;
            background-color: cyan;
        }

        .menu_pane {
            width:30%;
            height:100%;
            float: right;
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }

        .details {
            width:100%;
            direction:rtl;
        }

        .details h2 {
            padding-right:20px;
        }

        .details img {
            width:25%;
        }

    </style>
```

```html
<html lang="he">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>iNat_main_v2.html</title>
<body>
<div class="top_banner">
    <h1>Mine nature pictures</h1>
    <h4> Origin=https://israel.inaturalist.org/observations?place_id=any&user_id=shmuelabinun&verifiable=any</h4>
</div>
<div id="menu" class="main_menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#submenu" onclick=load_menu("./iNat_files/P_menu.html")>Plants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#submenu" onclick=load_menu("./iNat_files/B_menu.html")>Birds</a></li>
        <li><a href="#submenu" onclick=load_menu("./iNat_files/M_menu.html")>Mammals</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class='float-container'>
    <div class='main_pane' id="obs">
        <h2>ID=obs for Data Selected</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='menu_pane' id="submenu">
        <p>ID=SubMenue </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. *B_menu.html* - Birds menu

```html
<div class="submenu">
    <p> Birds to select </p>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#obs" onclick=load_detailed_data("./iNat_files/BID125.html")>אנפית בקר = Bubulcus ibis</a></li>
        <li><a href="#obs" onclick=load_detailed_data("./iNat_files/BID64.html")>אנפת לילה = Nycticorax nycticorax</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#obs" onclick=load_detailed_data("./iNat_files/BID124.html")>ברכיה = Anas platyrhynchos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#obs" onclick=load_detailed_data("./iNat_files/BID68.html")>דרור הבית = Passer domesticus</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#obs" onclick=load_detailed_data("./iNat_files/BID71.html")>דררה קרמר = Psittacula krameri</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#obs" onclick=load_detailed_data("./iNat_files/BID131.html")>חסידה לבנה = Ciconia ciconia</a>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

3. *BID25.html* - Ibis data to display:

```html
<div class="details">
    <h2> Birds </h2>
    <h2> Bubulcus ibis - אנפית בקר </h2>
    <img class="zoomA" src="./iNat_images/img125.jpg"/>
    <img class="zoomA" src="./iNat_images/img125_1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

4)Images used to display the Ibis data:
[img125.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvGb4.jpg)
[img125_1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4riDI.jpg)

Comment: In oredr to fetch a local html file I used the **iisexpress.exe** utility to simulate a server, and then used **localhost:8080** url to load the main/index.html file.